# Effect of adding gaussian noise to the input layer in a CNN

Tags: keras, noise

I often come across Keras code that adds GaussianNoise to the input, however its not clear to me what advantages does it offer to the learning.

```
input_img = layers.Input(t_x.shape[1:], name = 'RGB_Input') 
pp_in_layer = layers.GaussianNoise(GAUSSIAN_NOISE)(input_img)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding noise in the input data is equivalent to adding a **regularization term** to the objective function.

See [Training with Noise is Equivalent to Tikhonov Regularization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bishop-tikhonov-nc-95.pdf) and [Adding noise to the input of a model trained with a regularized objective](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.3250.pdf).